# Change PING script to TELNET script?

Tags: cmd, telnet

I need to turn this ping script into a telnet script which I'd like to configure the script to telnet to the address (on my separate target list *.txt file) & either:

connect/disconnect - write success results to file 
or 
fail - write fail results to file, 
& go to next record, then end...

HELP? :)

---

```
@echo off
cls
echo Ping test in progress... 
for /F %%i in (iplist.txt) do ping -n 3 -a %%i >> result.txt
echo .
echo .
echo Result is ready.
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply replace `ping` with `telnet`. For one thing, the `telnet` shipped with Windows isn't scriptable in the first place, so you'd have to jump through some hoops to make it work in a script. You'd be better off using a telnet that's actually scriptable, like [`plink`](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.62/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink-usage) from the [PuTTY suite](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/). Also telnet clients can talk to arbitrary services, so you need to specify where you want to connect to (a telnet server uses a different protocol than, say, a web server or a mail server).